# How do you enable Oracle VirtualBox's autostart daemon?

Tags: virtualbox

The obvious [gist from @reidransom](https://gist.github.com/reidransom/6042016) didn't work for me.

Comment: Self-answer because a client was having significant issues with the gist, which has something subtly wrong with it. I haven't figured out what though.

Answer (score 1):

Working through Section 9.24.3 of the [User Manual](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.8/UserManual.pdf), the following will allow all users to set virtual machines to autostart:

```bash
cat /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/org.virtualbox.vboxautostart.plist | sed '6s/true/false/' | sudo tee /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.vboxautostart.plist
sudo mkdir -p /etc/vbox/
echo 'default_policy = allow' | sudo tee /etc/vbox/autostart.cfg
VBoxManage modifyvm VM_NAME_HERE --autostart-enabled on
```

To restrict this ability to a single user, use this line instead:

```bash
echo 'default_policy = deny\nUSERNAME_HERE = {\nallow = true\n}' | sudo tee /etc/vbox/autostart.cfg
```